# Why does Hangouts give my contacts a different # when starting from Voice?

Tags: google-voice, google-hangouts

Sometimes a texting conversation on android hangouts says my friend's number is something I've never seen before - a 678 number.

I think this occurs when I began the conversation using my desktop chrome google voice.

Is this a know issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how Google Voice works by design.  Here is the relevant exert from the [Help](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115063?hl=en) article:

> Each time you place a call, instead of dialing the number you want to
>   reach, Google Voice dials a US-based direct access number. The Google
>   Voice server then forwards your call to the actual destination number.
>   This allows for faster call setup and the ability to place calls
>   without a data connection. These direct access numbers may show in
>   your phone's call log, or on your phone bill.
>
> A unique direct access phone number is assigned to each person that
>   you call. The direct access numbers are stored in the Google Voice
>   application, not in your Contacts. They can be purged from your phone
>   at any time by signing out of the Google Voice app.
>
> Direct access numbers are assigned randomly, and may include numbers
>   that are out of your local calling area, or even out of state. If you
>   don't have a nationwide calling plan, you may be charged long distance
>   rates by your carrier.

Basically unique, auto-generated numbers are assigned to your contacts as you dial them. These numbers don't change, but will be different from your contacts' actual telephone numbers.

Comment: So it makes sense to include this new number in my friend's contact info?

Comment: @Eliyahu I started to, mostly so that my outbound call log is even remotely recognizable. I just add the GV direct access number as a "DO NOT USE" custom label name.